# Save file as PDF using Microsoft Word's app

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word

I have a .docx file that would like to save as .pdf.

[image: Word Document]

If I click in the three dots in the upper right

[image: Android Word Document]

And clicking the Save As doesn't allow to change from .docx to .pdf

[image: Android Word Save As]

The way I managed to do up to this was to click Share As PDF and send to my email. Then, from there, download it. But surely there must have an easier option. Also this method didn't work all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of clicking Save As, click Print. Then, in the top there's a dropdown from where it's possible to select Save As PDF.

[image: Save as PDF in Word app Android]

Then click in the yellow circle with the download icon and the text PDF and select where you want the file to be saved. That's it.